# EF Core Collections using Automapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: automapper, ef-core-3.0, automapper-collections-ef-core

Given I have 2 classes, Foo and Bar:

```
public class Foo
{
  private readonly List<Bar> _bars = new List<Bar>();

  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars => _bars;

  public void AddBar(Bar bar)
  {
    _bars.Add(bar);
  }

  public static Foo Create(string name)
  {
    return new Foo { Name = name };
  }

  private Foo() { }
}

public class Bar
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public string Description { get; private set; }

  public static Bar Create(string description)
  {
    return new Bar { Description = description };
  }
}
```

With 2 corresponding DTOs,

```
public class BarDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class FooDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<BarDto> Bars { get; set; }

  public FooDto()
  {
    Bars = new List<BarDto>();
  }
}
```

And an AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore setup of

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
    cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<DemoContext>();
    cfg.CreateMap<BarDto, Bar>().EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.Id == dest.Id);
    cfg.CreateMap<FooDto, Foo>().ForMember(dest => dest.Bars, opt =>
    {
      opt.MapFrom(s => s.Bars);
      opt.UseDestinationValue();
    }).EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.Id == dest.Id);
});
```

I have a use case whereby the incoming FooDto may contain inserted, appended, updated and deleted items in the Bars collection which I am attempting to handle by:

1. Looking up the existing entity from the database
2. Mapping changes from the DTO to the entity
3. Saving the changes to the database

However the following code produces an `InvalidOperationException` exception stating that "*The instance of entity type 'Bar' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached*"

```
var fooToUpdate = db.Foos.Include(_ => _.Bars).FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == fooDto.Id);
mapper.Map(fooDto, fooToUpdate);
db.SaveChanges();
```

My understanding was that becuase I am setting `EqualityComparison` for the `BarDto -> Bar` mapping it should update the tracked entity and the save operation should succeed becuase it was referencing the same object?

I am not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way or simply missing somthing in the configuration.

**Update**

It seems the problem I am facing may be related to [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection/issues/132) issue on github.